# Monitoring data flow to /dev/null for a given process

Tags: centos, monitoring, file-descriptors

I have a process which reads out data from a custom PCI-e device using a custom driver. The program takes a file descriptor as an argument and writes the raw data to it.

I would like to test the data readout performance of this device/driver, however, I can only do it using this program. In order to eliminate possible hard disk write speed bottlenecks, I want to send this data to `/dev/null`.

How can I possibly monitor the volume of data going from this process to `/dev/null`? Could I hack around this with symlinks somehow? Possibly create some kind of a descriptor which would have "internal logic" to achieve what I want?

Comment: In case you don't get any answers, you might try `yourprogram 1 | dd bs=64k of=/dev/null` and periodically send SIGUSR1 to the dd process, which will print out some statistics.

Comment: Have a look at `pv`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv